# how to get the size of a record in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to get the size of a record in MySql if the table contains fields of type TEXT or BLOB?

is it possible to get the size of a record or table using sql statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To calculate the size of a string or blob in bytes, use [`LENGTH(YourColumn)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length).

To calculate the number of characters in a text string, use [`CHAR_LENGTH(YourTextColumn)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length).