# size of the record (in bytes) with Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is there a simple way to get a size of the record (in terms of the disk space it takes) with activerecord (my db is mysql)?

I have found several ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715487/how-to-get-mysql-row-size-in-gb), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570809/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-record-in-mysql)) answers offering a way of doing it with sql, I wonder if there is something built in into Activerecord, like `MyRecord.first.bytesize`.

Size of the table would also do, I need an average row size.

The purpose of this is estimating disk space requirements for a database.

---

UPDATE

I have also found [ObjectSpace.memsize_of](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-memsize_of)

```
require 'objspace'
ObjectSpace.memsize_of(MyRecord.first)
```

Is the size of the activerecord object equal to the size of the record in the database?

---

This seems to give the combined size of all the fields. I am casting to String all the fields that do not respond to `size`, such as timestamps.

```
record.attributes.keys.map{ |attr_name| record.send(attr_name)}.inject{|sum, attr| sum + (attr.respond_to?(:size) ? attr.size : attr.to_s.size)  }
```

---

And here is the comparison of results of these methods for the same record:

- combined size of all attributes (see above): **222**
- `Marshal::dum(record).size`: **2678**
- `ObjectSpace.memsize_of(record)`: **128**

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this with ActiveRecord.

Comment: I have implemented some quick solution that does what I need and I packed it into a [gem](https://github.com/bosskovic/memsizable) . I will probably improve on it later...

Answer (score 2):

An approximation of size can be found by using:

```
Marshal::dump(obj).size
```

Since you said, its for database sizing - The dump has name of classes and instance variables - it may be bit of overhead compared to absolute record size.

You may want to look at this answer for getting MySQL DB size -  [Database size calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627811/database-size-calculation) and [How to Get True Size of MySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714750/how-to-get-true-size-of-mysql-database)

Based on number of entities currently stored in DB, and size thus determined using above methods - you can extrapolate for sizing.

Comment: what is the difference between `Marshal::dump(obj).size` and `ObjectSpace.memsize_of(obj)` ? The former returns 10+ time bigger size.

Comment: I am not very sure.  Lets see if anybody else can throw some light.

Comment: `ObjectSpace.memsize_of` will be an accurate representation of the size of the Ruby object in memory, and more accurate than `Marshal`. Neither will be the same as the size of the database row.

Comment: Marshal.dump will include all the instance variables, eg those related to change tracking, associations, various caches etc. Memsize_of counts ruby memory footprint (eg an empty array is 40 bytes on a 64 bit platform) and doesn't include a lot of things

Comment: I thought so, that would explain the difference in size (when compared to other two approaches I listed).